# Why is Android Studio so slow after update to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 8

Tags: android-studio

I have updated my Android Studio to

```
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 8
Build #AI-221.5921.22.2211.8786657, built on June 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

and now it is extremely slow to respond to any code change, e.g. it takes minutes to properly highlight any code following the simplest of refactors.

i have also noticed that it is showing git information within all my code files.

I do not know how i have configured this change, however i have a feeling its because of this git integration that my development is now painfully slow.

has anybody else experienced a degradation in responsiveness since updating to this latest version of android studio?

how can i get back to being able to be productive?

Comment: I have the same problem, a small code change takes like 3 minutes to syntax highlight on electric eel

Comment: Simply stop using the Canary Build version for production.
It's a preview release not a release with which developers should work daily!

Comment: I agree to a large extent but Electric Eel is beta now and waiting 30+ seconds for highlighting/autocomplete is extreme

Comment: This has generally been my experience with Android Studio for the past couple of years:  It chugs 2GB RAM, takes about 10+ seconds for a single character keystroke to register, simply moving the mouse causes CPU to spike to 100%.  IntelliJ is now just as bad as Eclipse.  It used to not be nearly as bad but, for me, Arctic Fox really took it to the next level.  Congratulations, the rest of you now get to experience the pain of what I've experienced every time I've fired up Android Studio for the past two years!

Comment: For me build became faster after invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Installed Electric eel yesterday coming from Artic Fox.  What a disaster.  Going back.

Comment: still, at 20/03/2023 I am having the same problem where officially released electric ill

Comment: Electric Eel is a CPU hog!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse this is a Canary Build of Android Studio, the perfomance can not be expected to be on par with the other versions. The best thing you can do is to consider downgrading to Android Studio Dolphin until the new version is in stable release.

Also the sluggish performance can come from the new Live Code feature:

[Live Code](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/08/android-studio-electric-eel-canary-9.html)
that makes building obsolete. Due to the feature not being finished, it might be that the coding experience you have might be bad.

Comment: Electric Eel is beta now, with Flamingo being canary, so I’m thinking big performance issues like this should be solved by now in a beta version. I do use Dolphin which does not have this problem. I hope you are right that it will be resolved once stable

Comment: It's not fixed on stable version.

Comment: yes, it's still incredibly slow. I had to downgrade to dolphin patch 1.

Answer (score 4):

I upgraded to the release version of Electric Eel when it prompted me I have just gone to the downloads site to download Dolphin again as it's running really slowly.

I make a change and then sit and wait for it to take affect before I make another. I'm posting this as a warning as I found this thread when I was searching for why Electric Eel was so slow.

If you've done the same as me you can download the old versions at:

[Android Studio Archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded last week to Electric Eel, but it is consuming almost 3GB, and even with that amount of memory it responds to a lot of tools VERY slowly (i.e. working on xml files)

It takes several seconds to show any option.

On the upside: Seems to me that contextual documentation loads faster.

Going back to Dolphin until this gets better.

**UPDATE**

To completely uninstall Electric Eel I had to download the zip file of an old Android version (old versions are in https://developer.android.com/studio/archive, I downloaded Android Studio 4.1 Canary 2) and use that uninstaller.

I installed Dolphin afterwards, but spent several hours trying to install my app in a physical device...Dolphin always got stuck in the build phase, but no message saying there was something wrong. I thought it was the ADB, but no, it was detecting correctly the phone. I tried with another app I developed and it worked OK.

So I decided to upgrade Dolphin to Electric Eel again, to see what changed, and after starting up Electric Eel showed a window saying that my project was built with AGP 7.3.1 but synced with 7.3.0. I synced it as recommended and I could install it again in the phone.

I post this in case someone faces the same situation...

Now I am again at Electric Eel, checking if it behaves better...